# Splitting a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, how can I get three different substrings for the date, month, and year  from the following string:   "12/15/2009" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do any more complex date manipulation, you can also convert the string to a [JavaScript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) like this:

```
var date = new Date("12/15/2009");
alert(date.getFullYear());
alert(date.getMonth() + 1);
alert(date.getDate());

var newYear = new Date("1/1/2010");
alert((new Date(newYear - date)).getDate() + " days till the new year");
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var date = "12/15/2009";
var parts = date.split("/");

alert(parts[0]); // 12
alert(parts[1]); // 15
alert(parts[2]); // 2009
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the .split() method to break apart the string.

```
var strDate = "12/15/2009";
var arrDate = strDate.split('/');

var month = arrDate[0];
var day = arrDate[1];
var year = arrDate[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want, "12","15", and "2009"? if yes following would return 3 string array.

```
"12/15/2009".split("/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var dateString = "12/15/2009";
var dateParts = dateString.split("/");
var month = dateParts[0];
var day = dateParts[1];
var year = dateParts[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var splitDate = "12/15/2009".split("/");
var month = splitDate[0];
var day = splitDate[1];
var year = splitDate[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

try using [yourstring].split(char splitter) to achieve the desired result (i.E. date.split("/")). This will yield a string array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to split the string :

```
var list = "12/15/2009".split('/');
var year = list[2];
var month = list[0];
var day = list[1];
console.log(day, month, year);
```

Will get you :

```
15 12 2009
```